# Teamviewer can't remote when turn off screen

Tags: display, remote, teamviewer

I can't remote by teamviewer when screen is turn off. When I turn it on, the remote work normally.
Who can help me? Thanks u so much!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is normal. If you use teamviewer and lock the session, its also blanked out for the remote side. Just turning off the screen will also not work if the screen itself uses HDMI, Display Port or DVI-D. Reason is, that as soon as you turn off the display, it is uninstalled from windows until you turn it back on.

If you want to be able to remote into a computer and not care for the screen being turned off, use Microsoft Remote Desktop. Any client where you share the screen with the remote user will not work for the same reason.

If you absolutely must use Teamviewer, leave the screen on. Teamviewer has an option that once you connect, you can blank the screen. Its not entirely the same, but that is the best Teamviewer offers.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to remote TeamViewer when the screen is turned off, as long as the screen is connected to the computer.

If TeamViewer is black screen, in TeamViewer do: "View" -> "Refresh".